# IndexError: List index out of range - creating 2d array of random numbers

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I am trying to generate a 2d array of random numbers in python, I attempt the following but it returns an indexError list index out of range. I don't understand why this is happening.

```
from random import random
n=10
t=5
Prob=[[] for x in xrange(n)]


for i in range(n):
   for j in range(t):
      Prob[i][j].append(random())
print(Prob)
print(Prob[1][1])
```

I appreciate any help on this 
Thanks

Comment: After you create `Prob`, you should print it out and see how it looks. It looks like `[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]` , When `i` and `j` start as 0, `Prob[0]` would look like `[]`. Thus `Prob[0][0]` makes no sense, that's an empty list, there's no item at 0th index.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way using [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

```
# generate 6 numbers between 0 to 100
import numpy as np
np.random.randint(0, 100, 6).reshape(-1, 2)
```

You can fix your code like this:

```
from random import random
n=10
t=5
Prob=[[] for x in range(n)]


for i in range(n):
    for j in range(t):
        Prob[i].append(random())

print(Prob)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, However, when you go away and reference it in another loop how do you call it up? because it hasn't got a j identifier!

Comment: To explain my previous comment further, If I want to refer to a specific element in the array in say vba or fortan I would do ```Prob(i,j)```  and then if I want the 1st entry of the 2d array I would do ```Prob(1,1)``` what is the equivalent in python?